# Syntax highlighting not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5040555/), I put the following just above the xml, and there's still no syntax highlighting:

```
<!-- language: xml -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It properly added "lang-xml" class but looks like stackoverflow does not add "prettyprint" css class, if there is no valid language tag, so prettifier does not render at all.

I have added the tag [java](/questions/tagged/java) and now working.