# Please add a "prettyprint" class when explicitly defined class with <!-- language: something -->

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Please add a "prettyprint" CSS class when explicitly defining class with

```
<!-- language: something -->
```

regardless of there being no valid language tag.

It is inspired by question *[Syntax highlighting not working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82028)*.

Comment: what is the problem with the current highlighting?

Comment: @Warren, it doesn't work, *unless* Prettyprint has already been enabled using tags. See [Manually specify language for syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971) for today's enhancements to the earlier [Changes to syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting). The latter was only based on tags, but those tags are still needed to make manually specifying the language work.

Comment: I'd say it's a bug, not a feature request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code with no matching tags for language will now be prettified if they have an override after the next deploy.

Comment: What does the override syntax look like?

Comment: <!-- language: something --> like above

Comment: @jjnguy, see [Manually specify language for syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971).

Comment: @jjnguy, just in case you read the linked post before I merged Kevin's edit: this is all based on *tag names*, not on language names.

Comment: Confirmed. But it seems the `class` is added to the HTML upon saving, so the few existing cases (if any) where it's lacking need a dummy edit.

Comment: @Arjan you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

To enhance on this a bit: without any language tags in the question, the following should work too. After the first deployment it did output `<pre class="lang-html"><code> ... </code></pre>` but without the additional `class="prettyprint"` the syntax highlighting was not triggered.

```
<!-- language: html -->

    While not hinted otherwise: <html> source <b>goes</b> "here".

<!-- language: javascript -->

    var a = 3;
    while(not (a > 0)){
      alert("JavaScript code <b>goes</b> here.");
    }
```

This [rendered without highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDAnq.png), but meanwhile things have been fixed. A new (dummy) save of the post gets one [the expected highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0YB4.png):

```
While not hinted otherwise: <html> source <b>goes</b> "here".
```

```js
var a = 3;
while(not (a > 0)){
  alert("JavaScript code <b>goes</b> here.");
}
```

The preview uses the default Prettify, which is fine to me.